# figuring out javascript equality operator

Tags: javascript

While trying to fully understand the difference between equality operator and identity operator, I came across an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ky6fyhws%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) at MSDN that explains what they both do, in terms of their inner workings, but I still had a few doubts and decided to create a flowchart so I could have a better picture. Now my question is, is this flowchart correct? or am I missing something?

It's also my understanding that the identity operator (===) would work pretty much the same way, but without attempting to convert A and B to boolean, number or string, in the first step. Is that correct?

You can see the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TswE3.jpg) too:

[image]

Ok here is the real thing, it was a matter of principles ;)

[image]

Comment: Good job with the chart!

Comment: There is no "identity operator", there is a strict equals (equality) operator though. If your question is "*does the flowchart model the abstract comparison algorithm that is used for the `==` operator*", the answer is "No". The best place to start is the specification: [*The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3).

Comment: You might compare that [*MSDN*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ky6fyhws%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) article to the equivalent on [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: Depending on the bibliography, you might find the operator as Strict Equality or Identity. [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) was what I needed. The MSDN article was a nightmare. Excellent, thanks!

Comment: This simple answer is **never** use ==, unless you know what you are doing and have a very good reason.

Comment: @user949300, you could extend that a bit to say never us js unless you know what you're doing. (I use == often, in fact I never use === unless I really have to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is this flowchart correct?

No. You should use the ECMAScript specification for the [*Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) to create the flowchart. *ToBoolean* is certainly not the first step (it's not used in **any** step).

> or am I missing something?

Yes, a lot.

> It's also my understanding that the identity operator (===) would work pretty much the same way, but without attempting to convert A and B to boolean, number or string, in the first step. Is that correct?

The [*Strict Equality Comparison Algorithm*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) is almost identical to the [*Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), there is a difference only if the argument Types are different, and in that case there is a precise order in which the Types are made equal before the comparison is made.

Comment: "and in that case there is a precise order in which the Types are made equal before the comparison is made." Not really. For strict comparison the types aren't made equal at all. If they aren't equal the answer is simply *false*.

Comment: @Octopus—that comment applies to the abstract equality algorithm, not strict (which, as you say, does not convert types).

Answer (score -2):

> is this flowchart correct?

No. Apart from being layouted terrible, it is misleading and partially wrong.

> Am I missing something?

Yes. The first step, "*try to convert A and B to boolean, string or number*" is wrong - that's not the first step in the [equality comparison algorithm](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3). Also, when to convert which of the variables to which type?

Then, the next step should be a type distinction, instead of repeatedly asking for identical values of a specific type.

The "last" step "*Can they (the types) be coerced into any of the last 5 situations? -> Coerce types*" lacks detail. All the detail. Which is the most relevant part of the sloppy equality comparison:

- Which types can be coerced?
- What types would be coerced to which?
- How does the coercion of the values work?

And no, after the coercion the algorithm pretty much starts at the beginning, not with the question about strings.

> It's also my understanding that the identity operator (===) would work pretty much the same way, but without attempting to convert A and B to boolean, number or string, in the first step.

That first step is not apparent in the actual algorithm, so No. In fact, `===` works the same *except the last step*, which coerces values into other types - instead, `false` is returned.

---

Edit: Your second diagram is accurate (correct), although it still features some odd layout decisions.